# bash: finding file without keyword

Tags: bash

I am looking for a command in bash that lists the files in which a keyword is not present. for listing files with the keyword I do

```
fgrep KEYWORD .
```

I was thinking I could feed `vimdiff` with two files with the lists, something like this

```
diff `fgrep KEYWORD .` `ls .` (THIS IS NOT CORRECT)
```

but I would not like to create two new files at hoc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using simple `grep` option.

```
grep -L "foo" *
```

You could use `--files-without-match` option too with it.